# Is there a reverse double-negation translation?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

There are many [double-negation translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) $f$, each with the property that $\vdash\varphi$ classically iff $\vdash f(\varphi)$ intuitionistically.  Is there a translation the other way?  Specifically, I mean, is there a function $f$ on formulae such that $\vdash\varphi$ intuitionistically iff $\vdash f(\varphi)$ classically?

For the purposes of this question, let us consider only propositional (intuitionistic and classical) logic, even though the double-negation translations mentioned above generalize to first-order logic.

Even in just the propositional case, given the difference in complexity between the two logics' semantics, one would expect any such $f$ would increase the size/complexity of its argument, perhaps even a lot.  But making the translation as efficient as possible is a secondary (bonus?) question that comes after the question of whether such a translation exists at all.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no", but I don't have a proof or a reference. The idea is that clasiscal logic _is_ intuitionistic logic plus a ~bonus axiom~ (LEM). So to simulate classical logic intuitionistically, all we need to do is find a subset of formulas validating that bonus axiom, and the double-negated ones fit the bill (there's more to say here, obviously, but comments are short). Conversely, once you _have_ access to the bonus axiom, it's comparatively hard to restrict its use.

Comment: That said, if you're willing to expand your classical language slightly to allow a new symbol $\square$, then we _can_ interpret intuitionistic logic classically by embedding it into a [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), for instance, S4. If you like, I can write up an answer to this effect, but I'm not sure if it actually answers your question (which is why I'm leaving a comment instead)

Comment: For the first-order logic case, you could translate $\varphi$ to "the axioms of a Heyting algebra imply that for every assignment of values to the free variables of $\varphi$, the formula for $\varphi$ evaluates to $\top$".

Answer (score 10):

Based on an analysis of computational complexity, we should not expect any such $f$ to be computable in polynomial time.

It is well-known that the problem of determining whether $\vdash \phi$ classically is a co-NP complete problem, since its complement is trivially equivalent to the famous satisfiability problem, the first problem ever proved to be NP-complete.

It is less known, but still established in the literature, that the task of determining whether $\vdash \phi$ constructively is PSPACE-complete.

If we had a polynomial-time reduction $f$ from the intuitionist problem to the classical problem, this would prove that $PSPACE = co-NP = NP$. However, it is not presently known whether $PSPACE = NP$, nor is it even known whether $NP = co-NP$.

Of course, if we wanted to be silly, we could define $f(\phi) = \top$ if $\phi$ is an intuitionist tautology and $\bot$ otherwise. This would satisfy your criterion. But this function does not reveal much insight, and, as mentioned, computing $f(\phi)$ is a $PSPACE$-complete problem which we should not expect to be solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: Even though, as you say, this is not a full answer, it is still very helpful--thank you!  My interest in the question was to detect whether $\vdash\varphi$ intuitionistically by applying a SAT solver (some of which are remarkably fast) to check if $\vdash f(\varphi)$ classically.  Your comments suggest that $f(\varphi)$ will be very large, so this might not be a useful strategy--depending on how the output of $f$ comports with the optimizations of the SAT solver.